# Paytm integration in android app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, paytm

Can I implement Pay Tm app integration for payment gateway in my android app to provide pro version of an application instead of google payment option?  or which is best option other than google play ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link to the [payment guidelines](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/) for monetization on Google Play...

> Developers offering products within a game downloaded on Google Play or providing access to game content must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment.
>
> Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:
>
> - Payment is solely for physical products
> - Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

So, for any app on the Play store, Google in-app billing is used for content consumed within the app, such as unlocking the pro version of the app. For physical goods or digital goods consumed outside the app, other third party payment services are permitted.